# Nix shell fails to start for Plutus

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program

```
maciej@ola:~/workdir/plutus/plutus$ nix-env --version
nix-env (Nix) 2.3.12
```

Running the `nix-shell` command for the default.nix in [Plutus](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/blob/master/default.nix) and getting a genuine http 404 error that stops the whole nix shell from starting.

```
trying https://bintray.com/joneshf/generic/download_file?file_path=purty-6.2.0-linux.tar.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
error: cannot download download_file?file_path=purty-6.2.0-linux.tar.gz from any mirror
builder for '/nix/store/g0drypafpyzckkpwzplp9k9amx4bf7a4-download_file?file_path=purty-6.2.0-linux.tar.gz.drv' failed with exit code 1
building '/nix/store/a7wvz8wy4iqy5ynbx49lf23a4w7dxixg-drv.r29349.tar.xz.drv'...
cannot build derivation '/nix/store/wdgbj9xf3rz44xz5afw20m1ns0n8llpg-purty-6.2.0.drv': 1 dependencies couldn't be built
```

Git log

```
git log
commit e11d59a181f558fb5d2e5b0a2a32afd496660bc1 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
    Author: Jann Müller <j-mueller@users.noreply.github.com>
    Date:   Tue Jun 22 08:28:10 2021 +0200
```

Am I using a wrong Plutus branch? If so which branch / tag should I use to start the Plutus Playground.

Comment: I got stuck here, any ideas? I've done all steps needed, so not sure what the problem is. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAGL0.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAGL0.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just able to pull down the latest Plutus code and start a nix shell so I don't think it is the branch.

What does your binary cache configuration look like?
https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus#how-to-set-up-the-iohk-binary-caches

Comment: Neither the `/etc/nix/nix.conf` nor the `/.config/nix/nix.conf` exists, so I take I don't have caches set up.

Comment: I had to manually create these files on my machine

Comment: Thanks. The way I read it is this, could it be that you only managed to succeed to run nix-shell because you had binary caches specified, i.e., you downloaded the binaries without actually building plutus that is? Or did you succeed with running nix-shell without binary caches?

Comment: Actually, I don't need to build it if I can just use the binaries. Thanks.